# Pass "What went wrong" Gradle error message to another Job in Azure Pipelines

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, continuous-integration

**Context**: performing Android instrumentation (UI) tests with Azure Pipelines.

There are 2 jobs: one does the testing (launches an emulator and runs the tests), and the other job reports an error, if the previous job fails for some reason.

I have the following simple setup in my Azure Pipelines:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: SmokeTesting
    displayName: Smoke testing
    timeoutInMinutes: 60
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    steps:
      - script: meta/scripts.sh launch_avd
        displayName: Launch AVD
        workingDirectory: ''
      - task: Gradle@2
        displayName: Run smoke tests
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: ''
          gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
          publishJUnitResults: true
          tasks: ':app:connectedAndroidTest'
  - job: ReportFailure
    displayName: Report failure
    dependsOn:
      - SmokeTesting
    condition: or(failed(), canceled())
    steps:
      - script: meta/scripts.sh report_smoke_tests_error
        workingDirectory: ''
        env:
          BUILD_ID: $(Build.BuildId)
```

It all works as expected: if there is an error, the second job is run. In this case, the log in Azure Pipelines Web contains very useful information, that I would like to have access to in the second job:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 22.0.7026061. Versions available locally: 18.1.5063045, 21.3.6528147, 21.3.6528147
```

How do I get "What went wrong" message in my second job?

My idea is to use multi-stage variable to record the message in the first job, and then use it in the second one. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to get this message in the first place.

Comment: Specific reason for a separate job and not just a task with condition in the same job? Your smoke test script can use the set variable log string to set a variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable , or you could have the task open the log file and inspect its content. Putting the other task in a separate job makes things harder, cause it starts with a clean slate and you lose access to the context, log files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the [Build Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to get detailed build information. The api response contains the property `issues`, you can check the results there if there is an errors.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/build/builds/3838/timeline/?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

If the `issues` does not contain the error message you want, you can retrieve the content related to Gradle@2 task in the response body. Obtain the log url according to the property `log`.

[image]

By calling this log url, you can get the log of Gradle@2 task, and then parse the log to get the desired message.